# jQuery datePicker below UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, datepicker, z-index

See [Example](http://jsbin.com/ofipu)

After clicking the show container link the datepicker component - 2nd input - is shown below the UI dialog. What should I do to show it above the UI dialog?

Answer (score 7):

You could set the z-index of .ui-datepicker to 1003.

```
.ui-datepicker
{
  z-index: 1003;
}
```

Right now, .ui-widget-overlay has a z-index of 1001 and the .ui-dialog has a z-index of 1002. The datepicker has no z-index, and defaults to being below the z-index of these others. Up it to a higher z-index and it should appear above the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but the datepicker dialog had a `style="z-index:1"` which was wreaking me.

So I had to add the `!important` keyword.

```
.ui-datepicker {
  z-index: 1003 !important;
}
```

Comment: all those suggestions to override z-index were driving me nuts! `!important` was the thing that i was missing

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on the datepicker, e.g.:

```
.ui-datepicker 
{
    z-index:20000;
}
```

Should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the its an old browser (IE6) you may need the 'BGIFrame' plugin and set the dialog option to use it, if the z-index didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed by adding this on JS

```
  //allow interaction of select2, date and time picker on jQuery UI dialog
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(e) {
    return !!$(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog, .ui-datepicker, .select2-drop').length;
  };
```